# MySQL DATE_ADD() period from another table

Tags: mysql, date

I need to get MySQL Server Date using the following statement:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR) - This Works as expected.
```

But now I need to have the period (SECOND, HOUR, WEEK and etc.) in another table in database, so I tried the following.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 duration_table.period) FROM (SELECT 'HOUR' period) as duration_table;
```

But it doesn't work. So, is there way to provide period as a string to DATE_ADD function?

P.S. I can't use PHP to generate this query, I don't want to use CASE sentence on it.

Comment: The periods are not values, they're literals in the query. The only way to do this is with a CASE expression or dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `CASE` expression.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), CASE duration_table.period
                        WHEN 'HOUR' THEN INTERVAL 1 HOUR
                        WHEN 'SECOND' THEN INTERVAL 1 SECOND
                        WHEN 'WEEK' THEN INTERVAL 1 WEEK
                        ...
                       END)
FROM ...
```

If you don't want to do this, why not just put the number of seconds in the duration table, rather than a period name?

The only other alternative I can think of is preparing dynamic SQL.

Comment: I was thinking about this to put seconds, but then it will be hard coded. So  if there is no other option I will use it

Comment: What's wrong with that? The number of seconds in a day or week is not going to change.

Comment: Ok, lets take 1 MONTH, month have 28-31 days, same with YEAR - 355-356

Comment: Yeah, months don't work properly like that. I was hoping you weren't interested in them.